# Change the alignment of text in a paragraph with contenteditable attribute as true

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm creating a section in which I can add paragraphs and want to change the alignment of the text inside the paragraph to Left, centre or right.

I tried selecting the text inside the paragraph and then hitting the button connected to execCommand to align centre and all but that didn't change anything

Button to change the alignment to center

```
<button id="center" class="btn btn-secondary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></span>
</button>
```

Page area which has the content to edit and change the alignment

```
<div class="page" id="page">
    <p class="content-border" contenteditable="true" width="fit-content">Change this text</p>
</div>
```

jQuery script to execute the justify center command

```
$("#center").click(function () {
     document.execCommand( "justifyCenter", false, "" );
 });
```

Comment: it might be unnecessary to ask, but did you imported `jQuery` to your codebase?

Comment: Yes, I have imported it. The other bold or Italic commands are working just fine. It's just the case with this alignment thing.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing on? It seems that `document.execCommand()` isn't well supported in some browsers (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I'm using Firefox 68.0

Comment: Are there any error messages and can you share them?

Comment: No there aren't any error messages. I added a console output before and after the execCommand call and they both get printed normally.

Comment: And did you inspect the element w/ i.e. Firebug/Firefox dev tools? It might be that proper styling is applied, but you don't see it due to css overwrites or something

Comment: No, there are no such errors with overwrites.